# Cound`t check values in datalist c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 protected void ImageButton16_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["login"].ToString() == "true")
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataListItem Item in DataList1.Items)
            {
                Label id = (Label)DataList1.Controls[i].FindControl("ID");
                Label bidcount = (Label)DataList1.Controls[i].FindControl("Label7");
                string email = Session["username"].ToString();
                TextBox bid = (TextBox)DataList1.Controls[i].FindControl("TextBox1");
                if (bid.Text != "")
                {
                if (int.Parse(bid.Text) < int.Parse(bidcount.Text))
                {


                String script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> ";
                script += "AddConfirmbid()";
                script += "</SCRIPT>";
                Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ClientScript", script);
                }
                else
                {
                    String script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> ";
                    script += "invalidbid()";
                    script += "</SCRIPT>";
                    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ClientScript", script);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                String script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> ";
                script += "enterbid()";
                script += "</SCRIPT>";
                Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ClientScript", script);
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        String script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> ";
        script += "login()";
        script += "</SCRIPT>";
        Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ClientScript", script);
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you be more specific ?

Comment: i want know what is the wrong in here..it gives incorrect string for mat..when i put values in to the textbox...

Comment: some one please help me to figure this

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code that your are  searching textbox in wrong way. I hope blow code will help you out to get textbox correct value.

```
foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
        {
            TextBox bid = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox1");

            string text = bid .text;
            // Do whatever you need with that string value here
        }
```

Comment: i have many items in the datbase.soo when i load the page..datalist retriew all the item with separately..that`s why i put for each loop..when i put value to textbox and enter bid button it says.. Input string was not in a correct format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: The error means that the string you're trying to parse an integer from doesn't actually contain a valid integer.  Also, check out the Int.TryParse method - it's much easier to use if the string might not actually contain an integer - it doesn't throw an exception so it's easier to recover from.

Comment: i have fixeed the error i convert it into double..then the error go away